# Perl DBIのbind_columnについて

Tags: perl

PerlのDBIを用いてselect文を実行し、各行を読み込み処理を行う際に

$sth->bind_columns(\$name, \$old, \$language);
while($sth->fetch()){
  ...
}

というコードを実行しているのですが、DB上の$oldにデータが入っていない行の
while文中の処理が省略されて、次の行に移行してしまいます。

$oldが空の場合も処理を行うようにすればどうすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 1):

コメントにしようかと思ったのですが実際のコードを含むのでこちらにします。

質問にはいくつか重要な情報が抜けています。
まずは実行可能なコードを提示し、何が問題になっているのか具体的に教えてもらえますか？

以下はSQLiteでテストした時のコードと結果です。$oldがカラでも問題なく処理されているように見えます:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::SQLite;
use Data::Dumper;


# メモリ上のデータベースハンドラ
my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:SQLite:');

# foo, bar, buzだけ存在するtestテーブルの作成
$dbh->do(q{ create table test (name text, old text, language text) });

# テストデータを用意する
$dbh->do(q{
    insert into test ( name, old, language ) values ( ?, ?, ? )
}, undef, @{$_}) for (
    ['foo1', 'bar1', 'buz1'],
    ['foo2', undef,  'buz2'], # 意図的にbar2だけ抜く
    ['foo3', 'bar3', 'buz3'],
);

# name, old, language を取得するSQL
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{ select name, old, language from test });
$sth->execute;

# それぞれを $name, $old, $language に紐付ける
my ($name, $old, $language);
$sth->bind_columns(\$name, \$old, \$language);

while ($sth->fetch()) {
    print Dumper [$name, $old, $language];
}

$dbh->disconnect;
__END__
$VAR1 = [
          'foo1',
          'bar1',
          'buz1'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'foo2',
          undef,
          'buz2'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'foo3',
          'bar3',
          'buz3'
        ];
```